# "Unmapped members were found" errors after implementing IMultiTenant interface

Tags: abp

I am getting this "Unmapped members were found"  after adding IMultiTenant to my entity.
The "Car" database table already has the TenantId column created.

**"Car" Class under "Domain" project**

```
public class Car : Entity<Guid>, IMultiTenant
{
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Guid? TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

**"AutoMapper" Class under "Application" project**

```
public CarManagementApplicationAutoMapperProfile()
{
    CreateMap<Car, CarDto>();
    CreateMap<CarDto, Car>();
}
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not related with database. Object mapper is trying to map properties of Car <=> CarDto one-by-one. Check the error message carefully, it indicates which property couldn't be found.

Since you have mentioned it happens after adding IMultiTenant interface, high probably your **CarDto** doesn't have

```cs
public Guid? TenantId { get; set; }
```

property.